# Can the Properties (JavaBeans) already be used with Codename One?

Tags: properties, codenameone

I am interested in using Properties in my CodenameOne project, namely because properties can be observed. I searched and found this [blog post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/properties.html) which starts by announcing

> We [Codename One committers] committed properties as a deprecated API

but then the blog post seems to tell it still could be in active development see

> The code below is preliminary and the syntax/classes might change without warning

The code presented in the blog post is not testable on my project. Indeed the following code does not work :

```
public class User implements PropertyBusinessObject {
 // Do stuff
}
```

because the PropertyBusinessObject interface does not exist in my project. How could the PropertyBusinessObject interface be defined, what should it extend ? And by the way are Properties already available ?

Thank you very much for helping me sorting this out in my mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure they've been available for a while. Just use Update Client Libs in the Codename One settings under the basics section. Once you do that you will have the latest libraries.

When you create a new project in the IDE it uses the libraries it has locally not necessarily the latest.

Comment: Thanks @Shai, is there a demo that uses this mechanism that I could have a look at to better understand how it works ?

Comment: Not yet. This is still in the experimental/seeking feedback stage so a demo would imply usage. I'm working on a demo which I'm using internally but it's in no shape for public consumption. The code doesn't look much different from what we have in the blog post.